# xcode pass object using segue

Tags: xcode, object, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to pass an object from a view controller to another one.
In the destinationController I have:

```
@interface destinationController : UITableViewController{
    destinationController *object;
@property(nonatomic,copy) destinationController *object;
```

In the viewController containing the information I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"destinationController" sender:self];

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"destinationController"])
{
    destinationController *dC =[segue destinationViewController];
    NSInteger selected = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
    dC.object=[vcArray objectAtIndex:selected];
```

where the vcArray contains numbers and names but I only want the selected row.
Trying to pass the selected object to the object in destinationController does not seem to work. Instead it gives me the error:

[viewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000140
2012-11-14 18:08:25.039 app[3314:13d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[viewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8000140'*** First throw call stack:
(0x18e6012 0x12abe7e 0x19714bd 0x18d5bbc 0x18d594e 0x12a8cc9 0x83b2 0x5c22 0x63aac7 0x2d5422 0x5a68 0x2a28d5 0x2a2b3d 0xca9e83 0x18a5376 0x18a4e06 0x188ca82 0x188bf44 0x188be1b 0x1dae7e3 0x1dae668 0x1f365c 0x1f4d 0x1e75)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I think the problem is that I am not assigning properly the object

Comment: Please update the question with the actual error showing which selector and which class it's complaining about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your property declaration:

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) destinationController *object;
```

This says that whenever you assign an object to this property, the object is copied.

But, as your error message says - you haven't implemented the methods required by the NSCopying protocol (which is where `copy` comes from).

You probably should change this declaration to:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) destinationController *object;
```

Comment: thx that seems to work. Array includes name and number but if I use object.name it does not find it. How can I get the name and number?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking about.

Comment: I mean if I write vcArray.name I will get the name in the array. Now that I have pass it in the dC.object how can I get the name from the object? I wrote in the destinationController NSLog(@"%@",spsObject.name); but it does not find variable name.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are asking. `vcArray` is an NSArray (I presume, since you are sending it an `objectAtIndex:` method. An array doesn't have a `name` property, so what you are saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was referring to the 'name' variable of my vcArray but never mind I will search for it. Thank you again for the answer